# Point Light shows black box & rect (PointLight not working) - libgdx 3D

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, shaders, lighting

I am creating a 3d scene currently a box and rect, and trying to enable lighting.

> When i create a PointLight and add it to Environment everything turns to  black color?

all i want to do is create a 3d scene and enable point light, like a sun or rays coming from a point and shading the objects.

Code:

```
environment = new Environment();
environment.add(new PointLight().set(1f, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 20f, 100f));

modelBatch=new ModelBatch();
```

..

```
square=new ModelBuilder().createBox(300,300,300,new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);
squareinst=new ModelInstance(square);
squareinst.transform.setTranslation(-500,0,0);
```

--

```
sprites.get(0).setRotationY(sprites.get(0).getRotationY() + 1f);
sprites.get(1).setRotationY(sprites.get(1).getRotationY() - 1f);
squareinst.transform.rotate(1,0,0,1);

modelBatch.begin(camera);
for(Sprite3D sp:sprites)// has 3d rect models
     sp.draw(modelBatch,environment);
modelBatch.render(squareinst,environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

PointLight turning everything black
[image]

Without using environment or lights
[image]

as per my investigation, here if pointlight is not working then everything should be black as currently, because the environment needs light, it works fine with Directional light (only the backface of rect is black even after rotations, i don't know why)

libgdx version 1.6.1 - android studio
i checked it on both android device and desktop

please i really need to get this PointLight working, i don't know if it will take a custom shader, if so please guide me to some links because i am not experienced in shaders. I also read about PointLight not working on some device or not working in opengl 2.0 enabled, but i am not sure.